# Console: Enter name until

Tags: vb6, console

```
Sub Main()
    Dim name1 As String
    Dim name2 As String

    Console.WriteLine("Enter name:")
    name1 = Console.ReadLine

    While name1 <> "x"

        name2 = name1

        Console.WriteLine("Enter name:")
        name1 = Console.ReadLine

    End While

    Console.WriteLine(name2)

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

I'm just a basic programmer trying to write a program to allow someone to enter a bunch of names until the user enters "x". However I can't get the program to display all the names at the end, once the user enters "x", I tried a lot of methods but I still have very basic knowledge.

Comment: I marked this as VB6 but I have doubts. Is it VB6 or VB.NET? Do you know?

Comment: It is VB.NET, not VB6.

Answer (score 0):

`name2` should not be a `String` but a "List of Strings". I will call it `names` as it makes more sense:

```
Dim names As New List(Of String)
```

Then in that `name2 = name1` line you should instead add `name1` to `names`. Use the `Add` method of the `names` list for that.

And at the end you must iterate over the whole `names` to print out the results. Use the `For Each` loop for that.

I have found a pretty good example that shows the three steps here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kf43ys3(v=vs.110).aspx